# My two BFS attempts to solve LeetCode 417 both encounter Errors

Tags: c++, queue, breadth-first-search, flood-fill

So I've been trying to solve [LeetCode 417. Pacific Atlantic Water Flow](https://leetcode.com/problems/pacific-atlantic-water-flow/) for almost 5 hours this afternoon, and I'm now very exhausted and frustrated cuz I really have no idea why my code doesn't work.

My DFS soluton passed LeetCode OJ (thank God) but unfortunately my two attempts to solve the problem with **BFS** all failed.

I really appreciate it if someone could help me out and tell me why my code doens't work and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

#### Attempt 1 Failed, Got Wrong Answer

**Wrong Answer, 8 / 113 test cases passed.**

105 cases didn't pass, error message below:

```
Input:
[[1,2,2,3,5],[3,2,3,4,4],[2,4,5,3,1],[6,7,1,4,5],[5,1,1,2,4]]
Output:
[[0,4],[4,0]]
Expected:
[[0,4],[1,3],[1,4],[2,2],[3,0],[3,1],[4,0]]
```

**My C++ Code**

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int m, n;
    vector<vector<int>> g;

    vector<vector<int>> pacificAtlantic(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        g = matrix;
        if (g.empty() || g[0].empty())  return res;
        m = g.size(), n = g[0].size();
        vector<vector<bool>> visitedPacific(m, vector<bool>(n, false));
        vector<vector<bool>> visitedAlantic(m, vector<bool>(n, false));

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)  {
            visitedPacific[i][0] = true;
            visitedAlantic[i][n-1] = true;
            bfs(i, 0, visitedPacific); // Left
            bfs(i, n - 1, visitedAlantic); // Right
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)  {
            visitedPacific[0][j] = true;
            visitedAlantic[m-1][j] = true;
            bfs(0, j, visitedPacific); // Top
            bfs(m - 1, j, visitedAlantic); // Bottom
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (visitedPacific[i][j] && visitedAlantic[i][j])
                    res.push_back({i, j});
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    void bfs(int x, int y, vector<vector<bool>> visited) {
        int dirs[] = {0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
        queue<pair<int, int>> q;
        q.push({x, y});
        while (!q.empty()) {
            pair<int, int> t = q.front(); q.pop();
            int tx = t.first, ty = t.second;
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                int a = tx + dirs[k], b = ty + dirs[k + 1];
                if (a >= 0 && a < m && b >= 0 && b < n && (g[a][b] >= g[tx][ty]) && !visited[a][b]) {
                    visited[a][b] = true;
                    q.push({a, b});
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### Attempt 2 Failed, Wrong Answer / Compile Error

I'm not sure what return type should I use. I tried two but all failed.

- The first one I tried was `vector<vector<int>> res;`, but I got Wrong Answer error message(1 / 113 test cases passed).
- The second one was `vector<pair<int, int>> res;`, and I also changed the original function return type name to `vector<pair<int, int>> pacificAtlantic(vector<vector<int>>& matrix){}`, but got Compile Error message.

**Wrong Answer**

1 / 113 test cases passed. which means 112 test cases didn't pass.

```
Input:
[[1,2,2,3,5],[3,2,3,4,4],[2,4,5,3,1],[6,7,1,4,5],[5,1,1,2,4]]
Output:
[]
Expected:
[[0,4],[1,3],[1,4],[2,2],[3,0],[3,1],[4,0]]
```

**Compile Error**

```
Line 69: Char 27: error: no viable conversion from 'vector<pair<int, int>>' to 'vector<vector<int>>'
      vector<vector<int>> ret = Solution().pacificAtlantic(param_1); return ret;
                          ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**My C++ Code v2**

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int m, n;
    vector<vector<int>> g;
    // vector<vector<int>> res;
    vector<pair<int, int>> res;

    // vector<vector<int>> pacificAtlantic(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> pacificAtlantic(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        g = matrix;
        if (g.empty() || g[0].empty())  return res;
        m = g.size(), n = g[0].size();
        queue<pair<int, int>> qPacific;
        queue<pair<int, int>> qAtlantic;
        vector<vector<bool>> visitedPacific(m, vector<bool>(n));
        vector<vector<bool>> visitedAlantic(m, vector<bool>(n));

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)  {
            qPacific.push({i, 0}); // left
            qAtlantic.push({i, n - 1}); // right
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)  {
            qPacific.push({0, j}); // top
            qAtlantic.push({m - 1, j}); // down
        }
        bfs(qPacific, visitedPacific);
        bfs(qAtlantic, visitedAlantic);

        // for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        //     for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //         if (visitedPacific[i][j] && visitedAlantic[i][j])
        //             res.push_back({i, j});
        //     }
        // }
        // return res;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (visitedPacific[i][j] && visitedAlantic[i][j])
                    res.emplace_back(i, j);
            }
        }
        return res;

    }

    void bfs(queue<pair<int, int>>& q, vector<vector<bool>> visited) {
        int dirs[] = {0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
        while (!q.empty()) {
            pair<int, int> t = q.front(); q.pop();
            int tx = t.first, ty = t.second;
            visited[tx][ty] = true;
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                int a = tx + dirs[k], b = ty + dirs[k + 1];
                if (a >= 0 && a < m && b >= 0 && b < n && (g[a][b] >= g[tx][ty]) && !visited[a][b]) {
                    visited[a][b] = true;
                    q.push({a, b});
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What don't you understand of the error message? `pacificAtlantic` returns a `vector<pair<int, int>>` and you're trying to put it into `ret` which is a `vector<vector<int>>`... I.e. don't use the pair, just a vector with two elements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I see why I got the wrong answer even when using the proper return type. I should have put `&` before the variable `visited` to declare it as a reference.